# "Window replacement company" or "Windows replacement company"

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

My client says:

> "We are a trusted windows and doors replacement company."

It sounds funny. It seems like it should be singular: *window and door*.

Although, if it is part of the name "Acme Windows and Doors" it sounds correct.

Comment: It does sound funny. Your instincts are correct.

Comment: Uhg.  This place is turning into Stack Overflow.  Uh oh, a new person joined up and asked a question that someone doesn't like - quick, downvote!  With a little rephrasing, this is a perfectly valid question - why is it a window and door replacement company, rather than a windows and doors replacement company?

Comment: Unfortunately, some people have a stated policy of down-voting if a question is not precisely on-topic and all tickety-boo.

Comment: A windows and doors replacement company sounds like one that markets operating systems to use instead of Windows on PCs and is an agent for tribute bands for the Doors.

Comment: @Eli *Turning* into? Please. There is a long, proud tradition here of heaping scorn on the heads of low-rep users. It's how we roll. And it works. Let's see if 3328674 ventures back. I wouldn't.

Comment: Agree with @Eli and deadrat. This is a perfectly appropriate question for ELU. +1

Answer (score -2):

I do think it would be window and door company.  I can't say why, grammatically, but I think it would be the same reason you go to the food store, gun store, pet store, and candy store, rather than the foods store, guns store, pets store, and candies store.